# Error while running move_group.launch ( MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Action client not connected: arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory )

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

While I launching move_group.launch I got the following error. i am trying to control my 6DOF arm(hardware) from moveit.  Can any one dare to fix my issue

```
[ERROR] [1381292999.635005693]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Action client not connected: arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
[move_group-1] process has died [pid 6684, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group __name:=move_group __log:=/home/unais/.ros/log/6883204e-309a-11e3-b71a-0c6076593c99/move_group-1.log].
```

log file: /home/unais/.ros/log/6883204e-309a-11e3-b71a-0c6076593c99/move_group-1*.log

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88946/error-while-running-move_group.launch---(-moveitsimplecontrollermanager:-action-client-not-connected:-arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory-)/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message is pretty explanatory -- the controller is unable to connect to the action specified. Does your driver actually expose a FollowJointTrajectoryAction interface named arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory?

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-10-08**:
hi, fergs .. I have not get an idea. Is it I need to edit any launch file? . As a newbe to move it I can't able to understand the naming .   What can i do to overcome this issue?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-10-08**:
You need to post more information for anyone to be able to help -- you have posted nothing about what robot/drivers you are using, or any details of your launch files or controllers.yaml.